# Oracle SQL - Same day last year (leap year proof)

Tags: sql, date, leap-year

I'm looking to find the same day last year in oracle sql. For example Wednesday, March 16, 2016 would be Wednesday, March 18, 2015 for last year.  So the closest day.

The following code worked good until the current leap year and broke after Feb 29th 2016.

this was my old statement which does not work for all dates:

NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(date, -12), 'iw')-2, TO_CHAR(date, 'DY'))

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you just want to subtract exactly 52*7 = 364 days to get the same day-of-the-week?

Comment: What do you mean by "same day last year"? The "same day" last year is the current date - 12 months or `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)`, at least in my book. For 29-Feb-2016 this will return 28-Feb-2015. Please edit your question and add whatever definition you're using for "same day last year". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract 7*52 = 364 days instead :-)

Comment: Note that on 31-Dec this will not return a day in the previous year. Same problem on 30-Dec during leap years. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis: That's exactly the same date the original query returned :-)  There's no workaround besides returning non-consecutive values like `2015-12-30 -> 2014-12-31` and `2015-12-31 -> 2014-12-25`

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be correct

**SQL Test:**

```
WITH data
     AS (    SELECT SYSDATE - (LEVEL - 1) this_year_date,
                    TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - (LEVEL - 1), 'D'))
                       this_year_day_of_week,
                    ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE - (LEVEL - 1), -12) last_year_date,
                    TO_NUMBER (
                       TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE - (LEVEL - 1), -12), 'D'))
                       last_year_day_of_week
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 300),
     crunching
     AS (SELECT data.*,
                (CASE
                    WHEN this_year_day_of_week > last_year_day_of_week
                    THEN
                       this_year_day_of_week - last_year_day_of_week
                    WHEN this_year_day_of_week = last_year_day_of_week
                    THEN
                       0
                    ELSE
                       last_year_day_of_week - this_year_day_of_week
                 END)
                   math
           FROM data)
SELECT TO_CHAR (crunching.this_year_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd Day') ty_date,
       math,
       (CASE
           WHEN math = 0
           THEN
              TO_CHAR (last_year_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd Day')
           WHEN math > 2
           THEN
              TO_CHAR ( (last_year_date - math) + 7, 'yyyy-MM-dd Day')
           ELSE
              TO_CHAR (last_year_date + math, 'yyyy-MM-dd Day')
        END)
          final_answer
  FROM crunching
```

SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/18211

**Output:**

TY_DATE MATH    FINAL_ANSWER

```
2016-03-17 Thursday     2   2015-03-19 Thursday 
2016-03-16 Wednesday    2   2015-03-18 Wednesday
2016-03-15 Tuesday      2   2015-03-17 Tuesday  
2016-03-14 Monday       5   2015-03-16 Monday   
2016-03-13 Sunday       5   2015-03-15 Sunday   
2016-03-12 Saturday     2   2015-03-14 Saturday 
2016-03-11 Friday       2   2015-03-13 Friday   
2016-03-10 Thursday     2   2015-03-12 Thursday 
2016-03-09 Wednesday    2   2015-03-11 Wednesday
2016-03-08 Tuesday      2   2015-03-10 Tuesday  
2016-03-07 Monday       5   2015-03-09 Monday   
2016-03-06 Sunday       5   2015-03-08 Sunday   
2016-03-05 Saturday     2   2015-03-07 Saturday 
2016-03-04 Friday       2   2015-03-06 Friday   
2016-03-03 Thursday     2   2015-03-05 Thursday 
2016-03-02 Wednesday    2   2015-03-04 Wednesday
2016-03-01 Tuesday      2   2015-03-03 Tuesday  
2016-02-29 Monday       5   2015-03-02 Monday   
2016-02-28 Sunday       6   2015-03-01 Sunday   
2016-02-27 Saturday     1   2015-02-28 Saturday 
2016-02-26 Friday       1   2015-02-27 Friday   
2016-02-25 Thursday     1   2015-02-26 Thursday 
2016-02-24 Wednesday    1   2015-02-25 Wednesday
2016-02-23 Tuesday      1   2015-02-24 Tuesday  
2016-02-22 Monday       1   2015-02-23 Monday   
2016-02-21 Sunday       6   2015-02-22 Sunday   
2016-02-20 Saturday     1   2015-02-21 Saturday 
2016-02-19 Friday       1   2015-02-20 Friday   
2016-02-18 Thursday     1   2015-02-19 Thursday 
2016-02-17 Wednesday    1   2015-02-18 Wednesday
```

Answer (score 0):

How about add_months( [date], -12 ) ?